help figuring out a two-lights three-way system
I need help figuring out this wiring so I can properly hook up my light fixtures.
The wiring was all done by a licensed electrician a few years ago when we did a complete house remodel, including complete electrical redo. The electrician also wired the switches, so I am working under the assumption all this part is correct. the current states noted are when no lamp is connected to either fixture, so just the connections as the electrician left it.
SW.A:it has 2 cables coming into the box, 3-conductor each which I will call 1 and 2. on the switch red1 (always on) is the left side traveller, red2 is the right side traveller (follow switch state), black1 (always on) is right side common (black screw). what you do not see in the picture is that Black2 is connected to White1 in the back along with black wires from another independent light switch, and white2 is also bundled with whites of other independent light switch.

SW.B: only one cable coming into this one. White connected to left side traveller (always live), red to right side traveller (always live), black to common (always live).

Light fixture A: three cables coming in, two 3-conductor and one 2-conductor. all bundled with like colored cables. when power is running, the black bundle is always live regardless of switch state, the red follows the switch state of SW.A but not SW.B.

Light Fixture B: three cables coming in also, but only one is 3-conductor, other two are 2-conductor cables. All black are bundled and always live, all white are bundled and neutral, one red wire follows switched state of SW.A but not SW.B.

given the red wires followed switch state of SW.A, I assumed I should connect lamp live to red, and neutral to white bundles. However when I do this, nothing turns on... and the behaviour of the switches changes, on SW.A only the left side red1 traveller is always live, and the right side red traveller and common follow switch state. On SW.B the white traveller is always live, and the right side traveller and common follow switch state.
EDIT: I've updated my post after some more troubleshooting, mainly specifying current flow.

Neutral must be white.  White can be different/not the same as neutral.  White can be hot(marked) or a traveller.

How do you know which switch terminal is the common?

Do you have a voltmeter?

My statement about the common is based on the pole on the switch with a black screw, and labeled "com" underneat. I do have voltmeter somewhere... I have also updated my post with the current flow when no lamp is connected, it is a bit different then my first description.

Just to be clear, did the electrician wire the switch arrangement, but you've never installed lamps until now, so it's never actually been proven to be wired correctly?

The existing wiring is incorrect, as noted in Robert Chapin's answer.  Unfortunately, there's no simple way to answer your question, because no-one has any idea how the wiring is configured.  So someone (either you or an electrician) is going to have to figure out what's actually there, and then figure out how to connect the wires to control the lights.
If you want to work it out yourself, I suggest you begin by fully labeling and documenting exactly what's there now.  Then you need to figure out three key things;

Where the power comes into this switching system (it could be at either of the switches, or either of the light fixtures).
Where the switched hot leaves the switching system, and goes to the lights.
Where each cable begins and ends.

Ultimately, all three way switches are configured like this:

You can see how the two switches work together to turn the lights on or off because changing the position of either switch will always change the state of the lights.  I'm referring to this as the "switching system' because it works as a unit to allow two switches to be used together to turn lights on and off, and is integrated into all three way switch circuits one way or another.  There are countless different ways to configure this basic arrangement, depending on where power comes into the switching system, where switched power leaves the switching system, and how the neutral is wired.
To figure out the 3 points above, you'll need to:

Shut off power to the circuit, and then disconnect all the wiring -
remove all wires from switches, and remove all wire nuts that tie
wires together.  (This is why you need to clearly label all cables,
and document all connections before doing anything.)
Find the power source within this circuit.  To do this, turn the circuit breaker back on, and use a multimeter to check voltage between all the wires and ground.  You should find one wire - probably black - which is hot.  That will be the 'source" - it may be in either one of the switchboxes, or in either of the light fixture boxes.
Find both ends of all the cables in the circuit.  Use the multimeter as a continuity tester to figure out where each cable within this circuit begins and ends.  One way to do this is to shut off power, and verify that nothing is hot, then temporarily tie together two wires at one end of one cable - for example the black and white wires at one end of one of the cables.  Then go one-by-one to all the other cable ends and check continuity between the black and white wires.  When you find the wires that show continuity, you've found the other end of that cable.  Repeat with all the other cables until you have created a complete map that shows the beginning and end of each cable.
Finally, you need to figure out which black or red wire travels from the output of the switching system to the first light fixture, and which wire then continues on to the second fixture.  This should be apparent once you have completed the previous two steps.

Once you've figured these things out, you can update your question with this information and people here can tell you exactly how to wire it.  Or you can probably figure it out yourself by looking for three way switching answers by Harper, who probably has an an answer which exactly matches your actual wiring configuration.

thank you for the detailed response, this makes a lot of sense. now that I think back on it, I think the switch were not installed by the electrician but by his assistant/apprentice at the time, and I remember us having similar wiring issue our electrician had to fix from the assistant incorrectly wiring another switch! I suspect the same thing happened here. I think I will just get him to come and fix this. thank you all for the help!


switch red1 (always on) is the left side traveller, red2 is the right side traveller

The "SW.A" is certainly wired wrong.  Using two different cables as travellers (red from each) for the same switch violates code.  This was likely hooked up by someone who thought red and black would go on those bottom two screws without checking if they were both traveller terminals.  In some switches they actually are next to each other like that, but not all switches are designed the same way.
The "SW.B" has the same problem.  You mentioned the white wire is spliced to the black wires at the other end.  That means the white wire was never intended to be on a traveller terminal.
